# Full-text schema in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm (extremely) new to ElasticSearch so forgive my potentially ridiculous question. I currently use MySQL to perform full-text searches, and want to move this to ElasticSearch. Currently my table has a fulltext index spanning three columns:

```
title,description,tags
```

In ES, each document would therefore have `title`, `description` and `tags` fields, allowing me to do a fulltext search for a general phrase, or filter on a given tag.

I also want to add further searchable fields such as `username` (so I can retrieve posts by a given user). So, how do I specify that a fulltext search should match `title` OR `description` OR `tags` but not `username`?

From the OR filter example, I'd assume I'd have to use something like this:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
           "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "title" : "foobar" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "description" : "foobar" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "tags" : "foobar" }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Coming at this new, it doesn't seem like this is very efficient. Is there a better way of doing this, or do I need to move the `username` field to a separate index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. 
I general I would suggest getting familiar with ElasticSearch mapping types and options. 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: Thanks - like I say I'm only just scratching the surface so far. After posting the question I did see that inside a query you can define a list of fields e.g. `{'fields' : ['a','b','c']}`, so I'm assuming this is equivalent with the above.

Comment: Yes, in ElasticSearch you usually have several ways of expressing what you want :-)